# Регулярное выражение (выбор блоков span из разметки)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть например такая переменная:

```
$htm = <<<<HTML
<div class="myClass">
.....
</div>
<div class="myClass">
<span class="cls">....</span>
<span class="cls6">....</span>
<span class="cls">....</span>
<span class="cls34">....</span>
<span class="cls">....</span>
</div>
<div class="myClass">
.....
</div>
......
......
<span class="cls">....</span>
<span class="cls2">....</span>
HTML;
```

т.е. переменная содержит html код, в котором встречаются элементы <span>, они могут находиться в разных блоках и вообще по всему коду разбросаны, как с помощью регулярки отпарсить их таким образом, чтоб получился массив, значения которого были эти span'ы, т.е.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count(array); $i++) {
echo $array[$i];
}
```

чтоб вывел span'ы вместе с их содержимым:

```
<span class="cls">....</span>
<span class="cls6">....</span>
<span class="cls">....</span>
<span class="cls34">....</span>
<span class="cls">....</span>
<span class="cls">....</span>
<span class="cls2">....</span>
```

Comment: Что конкретно не получается, какие варианты составлялись?

Comment: Попробуйте так:

    preg_match_all('/<span [^\/>].*<\/span>/i',$htm,$matches);

Comment: не работает, ничё не находит

Comment: А может это вы что-то не так делаете? Вот [пример в действии](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/exk-wus)

Comment: @Deonis, в условии было немного другое :) Только я не зря спросил что уже делалось - судя по постановке вопроса вообще ничего (задачка-то для упражнения с перврй же страницы учебника), поэтому выдавать готовые решения и водить за ручку тут можно долго...

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

)


выводит

Comment: почему? делал так

$html = preg_replace ("/ class=\"(.*)\"/ismU", "", $html);
preg_match("/^<span>(.*)<\/span>$/ism", $html, $matches);
но не совсем то что нужно выводит

Comment: @deonis наверно так должно быть  

    /<span [^\/>]*>.*<\/span>/i  
По Вашему примеру на phpfiddle выражение работает чудом, неся в себе ошибку.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте лучше библиотеку SimpleHTMLDOM. Регулярки не лучшее решение для парсинга html. На счет сложности не волнуйтесь, библиотека очень проста в использовании.

Comment: нужно именно регуляркой

Answer (score 2):

Для объявления строки подобным образом используется **три** угловые скобки

```
$htm = <<<HTML
<div class="myClass">
</div>
<div class="myClass">
<span class="cls">....</span>
<span class="cls6">....</span>
<span class="cls">....</span>
<span class="cls34">....</span>
<span class="cls">....</span>
</div>
<div class="myClass">
</div>
<span class="cls">....</span>
<span class="cls2">....</span>
HTML;

preg_match_all('~<span.*>.*</span>~Uis',$htm,$arr);
```

в `$arr` список span'ов с содержимым

---

вложенные span'ы могут доставить проблем, там нужен иной подход или пользоваться DOM

Comment: ничайно 4 написал

Comment: Ваше регулярное выражение в общем и целом на этом образце текста работает, но вот если внутри span будет перевод строки, то оно провалится.

Comment: @ReinRaus, теперь не провалиться

Answer (score 0):

```
@<span.*>.*</span>@i
```

Comment: Чем Ваше решение отличается от решения  @Gedweb, кроме того, что неправильно распарсит такие образцы текста:  

    1)
    <span>text1</span><span>text2</span>
    2)
    <span>te
    xt 3</span>
?

Comment: 1.) Не посмотрел что ответили уже (2й человек правильно).
2.) Был дан пример данных в которых чистые span теги ... без вложенных ... Есть запрос с условиями есть ответ по запросу. Вопросы ?